# How do I find the specific document insert_many() fails on?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, debugging, error-handling, pymongo-3.x

```
if (constant.gc in file.sheet_names):
            coll = db[constant.gc]
            print("Adding to " + constant.gc + " database")
            df = file.parse(constant.gc)
            df = clean(df)
            data_dict = df.to_dict('r')
            try:
                result = coll.insert_many(data_dict)
                nr_inserts = len(result.inserted_ids)
                print(str(nr_inserts) + "Cases added to database")
            except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as bwe:
                nr_inserts = bwe.details["nInserted"]
                print(nr_inserts)
```

I keep getting a NaTType error and I can't find which row of the dataframe has the blank date. Unfortunately, it's off of a 39k row Excel file. So, just looking through isn't going to help. I tried an except that theoretically could tell me how many were successfully inserted until the error, and therefore give me a hint on where to look, but it hasn't printed.

The error looks like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "dataimport.py", line 71, in importFromExcel
    result = coll.insert_many(data_dict)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 758, in insert_many
    blk.execute(write_concern, session=session)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 511, in execute
    return self.execute_command(generator, write_concern, session)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 345, in execute_command
    client._retry_with_session(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1384, in _retry_with_session
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 339, in retryable_bulk
    self._execute_command(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\bulk.py", line 295, in _execute_command
    result, to_send = bwc.execute(ops, client)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 898, in execute
    request_id, msg, to_send = self._batch_command(docs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 890, in _batch_command
    request_id, msg, to_send = _do_bulk_write_command(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 1382, in _do_bulk_write_command
    return _do_batched_op_msg(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 1307, in _do_batched_op_msg
    return _batched_op_msg(
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\nattype.pyx", line 64, in pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype._make_error_func.f
ValueError: NaTType does not support utcoffset
```

At a guess, ValueError and BulkWriteError are not the same, so nInserted never prints. Does anyone have an idea of how to get the number of successful inserts before the failure?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that any inserts are performed as the error is likely occurring before the data is passed to mongodb to insert.

In any case, if you want to hunt down which row in the dataframe has the NaT value, try: (subsitute `'date'` for your column containing the date)

```
null_df = df[pd.isnull(df['date'])]
print(null_df)
```

To remove null dated items use:

```
df = df[pd.notnull(df['date'])]
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Still learning the Pandas library. Looks like some people forgot to add in the date it was filed - is there no way to note a datetime object as null so that MongoDB will import it as such? I'll use 1/1/1970 if I have to, but I'd really prefer a null object that doesn't throw errors.

Comment: You can happily add a null date into pymongo as long as the field isn't a unique index or a validator prevents it. But the issue is not mongodb; it's the fact that the pymongo drivers don't know what to do with a NatType object. So either fillter out the NatType objects or convert them to something else before attempting the insert.